# order 20 group G and order 27 group H

Tags: group-theory, direct-product

GxH is direct product group of finite group G,H.
projective mapping

g: GxH -> G, g(x,y)=x
h: GxH -> H ,h(x,y)=y
is surjective homomorphism.

order of G is 20, order of H is 27.

S is subgourp of direct product group GxH
S = f (S) xg (S) for all subgroups of GxH.

I want to show that S is expressed as a direct product of G1 subgroup G1 and H subgroup H1.

20 and 27 are corprime, so they will be expressed as direct products, but I do not know. Help

Comment: The equation $S =  f(S) \times g(S)$ does not make sense. The function $f$ has not been defined and you cannot define a subgroup $S$ in terms of itself this way. Do you mean given $S \leq G \times H$ define a new subgroup $S_2 := g(S) \times h(S)$?

Comment: @Bysshed yes!
thank you for helping me

Comment: please consider using mathjax in your questions. It will improve the readability. Here is a tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference&ved=0ahUKEwinwZP1raLWAhUKaFAKHSN0DOkQFgglMAA&usg=AFQjCNEHTV_wrXwyk8b7I6mB9Kvo7DbtvA

Answer (score 1):

Given $S \leq G \times H$ define a new subgroup $S_2 := g(S) \times h(S)$. It is clear from the definition of the functions  $g$ and $h$ that $g(S) \leq G$ and $h(S) \leq H$.

To show $S_2$ is a direct product we need to show $g(S) \cap h(S) = \{ 1 \}$. Notice that $g(S) \cap h(S) \leq G$ and $g(S) \cap h(S) \leq H$. By Lagrange's theorem, the order of $g(S) \cap h(S)$ divides the order of $G$ and the order of $H$. But, as you noted, $20$ and $27$ are coprime and so $g(S) \cap h(S)$ has order $1$, as desired.